# tengo un error al construir un jar o war en el proyecto de spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

[image: [error]

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ms-usuariopanel: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tvradio:ms-usuariopanel:war:0.0.1: Failure to find com.tvradio:ms-general:jar:0.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
**

Comment: Hola @Luis, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: primero valida que en la carpeta .m2 de tu usuario se encuentre la ruta .m2\repository\com\tvradio\ms-general y dentro de esta ruta la carpeta de la version 0.0.1 y el archivo war. tambien puede eliminar la carpeta y reinstalar ms-general con el comando mvn -U clean install